# Losing the Č, č characters, UTF encoding within R

Tags: r

I have this string: `"Časové rozlíšenie súčet"`

I would like to store the string into csv file (or other) so I can use it later on for rewriting column names in a dataframe.

Using `write.csv(...., encoding="UTF-8)` or any other method, every time I get this:

```
"Casové rozlíšenie súcet"  # so it loses the Č or č, all other letters are fine.
```

I got the experssion from scrapping using `x <- fromJSON`. As soon as I put the scrapped string into `data.frame(x)` or `c(x)` I loose the `Č or č`, why is this happening?

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252         LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                            LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252
```

**EDIT:**

In my Rstudio console:

```
x <- c("Časové rozlíšenie súčet")
data.frame(x)

                          x
1    Casové rozlíšenie súcet
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The encoding you’re using – Windows-1252 – doesn’t contain the accented “c” letters.

Unfortunately, encoding support for R on Windows is rather lacking. If `Sys.setlocale`<sup>1</sup> doesn’t work, then the only recourse may be to `raw`-encode the string and convert it from there:

```
# Časové …
x = list(as.raw(c(0xC4, 0x8C, 0x61, 0x73, 0x6F, 0x76, 0xC3, 0xA9))) # , …
result = iconv(x, from = 'UTF-8')
```

Obviously this is a pain in the neck, since [you need to look up the UTF-8 encoding sequence for every character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/index.htm). A better way would be to read the data, *raw*, from a file and convert it from there.

I have no idea how to use this in conjunction with `fromJSON`. You may try specifying `encoding = 'UTF-8'` in the call to `fromJSON`. However, I doubt that’ll work.

---

<sup>1</sup> Try these:

```
Sys.setlocale(locale = 'en_GB.UTF-8')
Sys.setlocale(locale = 'UTF-8')
Sys.setlocale(locale = 'CP65001')
```

Unfortunately, I don’t know the state of the locale support for R under Windows so this might not work.

Comment: Thanks. I got the warning: OS reports request to set locale to "UTF-8" cannot be honored

Comment: @Max Ah, it seems that R simply cannot do that. Unfortunately encoding support for R on Windows is rather, ah, [*lacking*](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2013-November/067946.html). I’m not sure this will be fixed in the short term – UTF-8 on Windows is admittedly not trivial but there are also some misconceptions flying around on that linked mailing list thread (for instance, Windows *has* supported UTF-8 for ages, contrary to what’s claimed there).

Comment: Thanks, just reading about it: http://superuser.com/questions/221593/windows-7-utf-8-and-unicode